# Is it possible to disable WiFi and 3G on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am investigating whether it is possible to port an app of mine to iOS, and the features that are probably the most important, are:

- programmatically disabling any internet connection on the device
- detecting if the user tries to re-enable the connection and disable it again.

Is this possible somehow on iOS, and if it is - is it likely to be allowed on the appstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, it is not possible in non-jail-broken devices. This will for sure lead to the rejection of your application.

To enable this feature on any device, steal a class from **SpringBoard** (use the [SBWiFiManager.h](https://github.com/DjKira/iOS-6-Headers/blob/master/SpringBoard/SBWiFiManager.h) class reference).

```
[[_SBWifiManager sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: To enable this feature on non-jail-broken devices ??

Comment: @Thought-Beast: You can use this on any device. However, Apple will reject this.

Comment: @Thought-Beast: thanks for pointing out the mistake. I got it and edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible on iOS if you want you app in the app store.

Apple doesn't allow interaction with hardware at this level. You can detect connection type of the current internet connection and that is it.

On a jailbroken device this should be possible.